# How to set up XAML View Content in Different XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I just programm a Windows Universal App and I want to set up an
empty MainView.xaml witch provides the content from different User Control xamls just like in javafx and switch then on the fly in the MainViewxaml.cs like:

Pseudo Code:

```
this.Content = Login.xaml
```

Main.xaml Pseudo Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <UserControl x:Name="UserControl"/>
</Grid>
```

**My Question is:**

How can I do this in a Windows Universal app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a frame and pages. Or if you don't want to do that, use a ContentControl.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControl">
        <UserControl x:Name="UserControl"/>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

And than you can say ContentControl.Content = new YourUserControl();

Comment: ok it worked but only on device not on Emulator and the usercontrol grid is left up and not in centre as designed

Comment: Well if you don't provide us with any of your code it'll be hard for us to tell you what's wrong :)

Comment: their is no code is was a test and in the xaml.cs after initializing is added your example not more =P